# Is it possible to get uint256 value from Solidity using web3.js

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

So the question is pretty simple. I am calling contract method that returns uint256 value. Is it possible to get that value in JavaScript at all? As far as I understand JavaScript can't work with big numbers and the solution would be to make new contract that returns data as string? Right now I am getting a value that simply cuts a lot of zeros :)

Comment: ok, never mind... obviously you can just call .toString(); on the result you get and parse the needed value from it

Answer (score 1):

Web3 returns primitive data types (including `uint`) as strings. If you try to parse it into javascript native number with something like `parseInt`, it will fail.

To work with the big numbers received via web3, you have to use library which can handle them. One such library is `BigNumber.JS` https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

So you can then use it like this:

```
let result = BigNumber(await bigNumber.methods.getNum1().call());
```

and use math operations implemented by BigNumber.js

```
result = result.plus("99999999999999999999999999999999999999");
```

note that if you then simply try to use the result value itself

```
console.log(result);
```

you will get result like this

```
  BigNumber {
    s: 1,
    e: 38,
    c: [ 10000000213, 12312312312312, 45465777775431 ] }
```

Therefore you will probably want to cast it to the string in the end

```
console.log(result.toString());
```

to get result in readable form, like:

```
1.00000002131231231231231245465777775431e+38
```

Comment: Actually BignumberJS is already in Web3JS. So yes, I was getting this funny array as result and this was not obvious in documentation that you can simply call .toString() method on it to get the actual number as string